# Inaccurate zero eigenvalues for 7*7 matrix

Tags: matrix, precision-and-accuracy, eigenvalues

I have symbolic entries for all the elements of a 7*7 matrix. At the symbolic level `Eigenvalues` gives two zeroes and five others that are extremely complicated. At the same time `Det` evaluates to exactly zero.

I take this to mean that, no matter what values the symbols within the matrix are assigned, I will have at least two zero eigenvalues. Exactly zero eigenvalues.

However, when I assign values to the symbols by hand, for eg., `a=10; b=50`, and so on, and evaluate the same codes, `Eigenvalues` evaluates to give two eigenvalues of the order of 10^-12. For my purpose, this magnitude cannot be treated as a zero. And I am also in need of a different eigenvalue of the same matrix which is very small, of this order or even smaller, but is not exactly zero. So I need the zeroes to show up much more accurately.

I have tried adding `$MinPrecision=50` to my code before executing the rest of it. It does not help at all.

A similar question was posted, [Is there a good way to check, whether a small value produced numerically is a symbolic zero?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96806/is-there-a-good-way-to-check-whether-a-small-value-produced-numerically-is-a-sy)
However I could not decipher anything of use out of it. My code is as follows,

```
    $MinPrecision = 50;
    m = {{mm - g^2 + a^2, a*b, a*b, 30*bb1 , bb1, 0, 0}, {a*b, 
         mm - g^2 + h^2 + n^2 + b^2, b^2, j*b, j*b/30, -k*b, -k*b}, {a*b, 
         b^2, mm - g^2 + h^2 + n^2 + b^2, j*b, 
         j*b/30, -k*b, -k*b}, {30*bb1, j*b, j*b, 30*bb0, bb0, 0, 0}, {bb1, 
         j*b/30, j*b/30, bb0, bb0/30, 0, 0}, {0, -k*b, -k*b, 0, 0, bbn, 
         bbn}, {0, -k*b, -k*b, 0, 0, bbn, bbn}};
    Eigenvalues[m][[1]]
    Eigenvalues[m][[2]]
    Det[m]
```

The result as you can check is zero for all three evaluations.
However as soon as I plug values for the symbols, for example,

```
    mm = 10^4;
    g = 10;
    a = 0.01;
    b = 0.01;
    c = 0.01;
    h = 10;
    n = 10^-4;
    j = 300;
    k = 4000;
    bb0 = 500;
    bb1 = 100;
    bbn = 1000;
```

And then evaluate,

```
    Eigenvalues[m]
```

The output is

```
    {16402.3, 10000.8, 10000., 8514.34, 1999.2, 2.01348*10^-12, 
    1.22563*10^-13}
```

I need the two zeroes to go to higher precision. If possible, upto 10^-60.

Comment: This can't be answered without a concrete example, but very likely you used machine precision arithmetic, which works with ~15 digits. Then the result is expected.

Comment: `0.01` is a machine precision number. `$MinPrecision` takes no effect.  Try ``0.01`50`` instead.

Answer (score 5):

By specifying exact values for the variables you use, you can get accurate values for the eigenvalues.

For example, I would write

```
Block[{mm = 10^4,
  g = 10,
  a = 1/100,
  b = 1/100,
  c = 1/100,
  h = 10,
  n = 10^-4,
  j = 300,
  k = 4000,
  bb0 = 500,
  bb1 = 100,
  bbn = 1000},
 Eigenvalues[m]]
```

The results can be converted to approximate values if needed

```
N[%, 30]
(* {16402.3272337221591649788834496, 10000.7999287584546436217564124, 10000.0000000100000000000000000, 8514.33972434372538655954886552, 1999.20007985232747150647793915, 0,
  0} *)
```